# SimpleDateFormat Android неправильно работает

Tags: java, android

```
    runtime=runtime*1000;
    Log.e("DescriptionPagerCourse=onCreateView", runtime + "  ");
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    String strRuntime=simpleDateFormat.format(new Date(runtime));
```

Я получаю runtime = 7100; в секундах. Должно получиться 1 час и 57 минут. 
В итоге 9 часов и 57 минут. Почему?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm") вот так попробуйте

Comment: Может Вам подойдёт [`DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(long elapsedSeconds)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#formatElapsedTime(long))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное, всё дело в том, что метод `new Date(runtime)` принимает на вход количество миллисекунд, прошедших с 1 января 1970 года, судя по документации:

```
   /**
     * Allocates a <code>Date</code> object and initializes it to 
     * represent the specified number of milliseconds since the 
     * standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 
     * 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. 
     *
     * @param   date   the milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.
     * @see     java.lang.System#currentTimeMillis()
     */
```

Попробуйте так:

```
private static String timeConversion(int totalSeconds) {
    final int MINUTES_IN_HOUR = 60;
    final int SECONDS_IN_MINUTE = 60;

    int seconds = totalSeconds % SECONDS_IN_MINUTE;
    int totalMinutes = totalSeconds / SECONDS_IN_MINUTE;
    int minutes = totalMinutes % MINUTES_IN_HOUR;
    int hours = totalMinutes / MINUTES_IN_HOUR;
    return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
```

Этот метод, приняв на вход значение `7200`, выведет:

> 1:58:20

Answer (score 0):

Запустил Ваш пример. У меня вообще *04:58* выходит. Тут дело в часовых поясах.

Согласно документации к конструктору `Date`:

```
/**
     * Allocates a <code>Date</code> object and initializes it to
     * represent the specified number of milliseconds since the
     * standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1,
     * 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.
     *
     * @param   date   the milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.
     * @see     java.lang.System#currentTimeMillis()
     */
    public Date(long date) {
        fastTime = date;
    }
```

видим, что `long date` - это время в миллисекундах от указанной даты по **GMT**.

Вам необходимо скорректировать Ваш `runtime` согласно Вашему часовому поясу по GMT, а затем парсить.